# At what point should large functions be made static?

Tags: java, performance, optimization

When a function gets even moderately large, I generally change it to become static. For example, if a classes `toString()` gets pretty big, I usually change it to

```
public String toString()  {
   return  ClassName.toString(this);
}

private static final String toString(ClassName c_n)  {
    //.........
}
```

If the function is not excessively large, is it overkill to do this?

---

***EDIT***

I'm getting shot down big time here. :)

I understand how the static modifier should be used in general (for singletons, for stuff unrelated to a specific instance, for utility functions). I'm asking this from an *optimization* point of view: To avoid a large function's byte code from being duplicated in memory, for each instance of a class. I'm obviously wrong about how it works.

Comment: `"When a function gets even moderately large, I generally change it to become static."`  -- this makes no sense whatsoever. The correct behavior would be, "when a function gets moderately large, I consider refactoring it". Period.

Comment: I'm curious: Why did you think this might be advantageous? Passing an explicit reference to the object into a method doesn't save anything over the implicit version inherent in a non-static method call; all you've done is added another layer of call/return and broken any idiom which relies on "this".

Comment: `"I'm only asking this from an optimization point of view:..."` -- nope, makes no sense. The size of the method has no bearing on the efficiency of the code. Just get this concept out of your mind and move on. Sorry to be blunt, but you are quite confused.

Comment: Have you profiled your code? Do you know for a fact that you are causing a bottleneck due to this method? If not, don't make any assumptions, and certainly don't throw the OOPs baby out with the bath water based on this criteria.

Comment: I thought it was a memory usage thing, not a processing bottleneck: That that function's byte-code was being duplicated for each instance. I thought that making a large method static--only behind the scenes, and never seen in an API or used by users of my code!--would avoid this duplication. Although I don't understand it yet, based on the reaction and down-votes to this question, I am pretty clear on the *depth* of my wrong-ness.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Making the function static depending on the length of the function is totally wrong. Static variables/method are belong to class, not to instances.

So, if there are common functionality between the instances, not depending on any instances, then they can be static.

Here, you have made the `toString()` as static. But, this method should be describe an instance. Making this as static will give error prone results.

***Does it make sense to call this method, even if no object has been constructed yet?" If so, it should definitely be static. Otherwise, that should be instance method***

Answer (score 3):

You should make a method `static` **if it doesn't depends of an instance** of the class where it is declared. It has *nothing to do with the length of the function*.

Answer (score 0):

Code (methods) is not replicated per instance, it doesn't need to as it is the same for all instances and is not modified.

Only instance data (properties) is replicated.